# Overlay values on BoxChart Matlab plots (when using 'groupbycolor')

Tags: matlab

I would like to overlay all the values (not just the outliers) on top of a boxchart such that they are displayed over the corresponding categories.

MWE shows the box and whisker plots:

```
tbl = table;
h=100;
tbl.cat = categorical(randi([1,4],h,1 ));
tbl.y = rand(h,1);
tbl.color = randi([5,8],h,1 );
% figure
boxchart(tbl.cat,tbl.y,'groupbycolor',tbl.color)
legend(Interpreter="none",AutoUpdate='off',Location="northeastoutside")
         %% create division lines between categories, useful so I thought nice to share
        for iDivide = 0:height(gca().XAxis.Categories)                
             line([iDivide+0.5, iDivide+0.5],[min(ylim),max(ylim)],'Color','black','LineStyle',':')
        end
```

[image: boxchart]

I found a related example (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/398012-adding-a-scatter-of-points-to-a-boxplot#comment_2180020) showing the use of swarmchart to overlay the values. However, the results do not align with the additional use of 'groupbycolor' categories.

```
    hold on
    swarmchart(tbl.cat,tbl.y,[],tbl.color)
```

[image: boxchart with swarmchart]

- Is there a way to overlay the values from each of the categories and subcategories from 'groupbycolor' over a boxchart?
- Is there a way to modify the xaxis location for the values displayed using swarmchart so that the categories align with those from boxchart?

Many thanks in advance,

Jesse

Comment: You might file the `daboxplot` FileExchange entry interesting: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/74851-daboxplot (or any of the other boxplot tools on FileExchange). Or you could just `hold on` and `plot( x, y, 'ok' )` where `x` and `y` are the subset of points for each box, similar to what you've done for the dividing lines

Comment: I am having trouble getting `daboxplot` to work. I have one column of data, and two columns which are the x axis categories and 'groupbycolor' categories. For daboxplot, there are separate data columns for each of the xaxis categories and another 'groups' column. All the columns have the same length, which is not the case for me... Is there a way around this? Using `plot( x, y, 'ok' )` looping over each of the categories would be good (after adding some xjitter), however I dont know how to get the xcoordinates for each of the groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picture the space between the divider lines you've added

- There's 4 coloured boxes
- Each bar occupies an area on the x-axis which is `space`, `box`, `space`
- The spacing from left to right in each block is therefore `sbssbssbssbs`, or `sbs` for each of the 4 bars.
- Each category, or block of these coloured boxes, is centred around an integer, so the `sbs..` sequence starts from an integer minus 0.5.

Therefore we know the x position for the centre of box `icol` within category `icat` is

```
x = icat - 0.5 + ...   % start from left of "block" for this cateogry
    s + (b/2) + ...    % at least one space plus half the first box
    (icol-1)*(s+b+s);  % shift by one "sbs" width for each colour
```

The boxwidth by default is `0.5` (within its own space, not of the whole axis), but you can set that in `boxplot` to be explicit. Then we have something like this:

```
b = 0.5; % box width
boxchart(tbl.cat,tbl.y,'groupbycolor',tbl.color,'BoxWidth',b)

ucol = unique(tbl.color); % unique colours    (sorted)
ucat = unique(tbl.cat);   % unique categories (sorted)

s = (1-b)/(2*numel(ucol)); % spacing left & right of each box
b = b / numel(ucol);       % actual box width within each category

% Overlay points on each box, per unique combo of category and colour
hold on;
for icat = 1:numel(ucat)
    for icol = 1:numel(ucol)
        % Index of rows for this bar's data
        idx = (tbl.cat == ucat(icat)) & (tbl.color == ucol(icol));
        % Work out the x-axis position
        x = icat - 0.5 + s + (b/2) + (icol-1)*(s+b+s);
        % Plot the individual points
        plot( x*ones(nnz(idx),1), tbl.y(idx), 'xk', 'handlevis', 0 );
    end
end
```

You can style the `plot` however you want, I've added the `'HandleVisibility', 'off'` input here to hide the additional markers from the legend.

Example output:

[image: bar with all points]